# Rails query for Data over the past months

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to query for the number of messages sent over the last months, i use something like this to find out the last 6 months by name

```
gon.now_month_label = (Date.today).strftime("%B")
gon.now_month_data = 
gon.one_month_ago_label = (Date.today - 1.month).strftime("%B")
gon.one_month_ago_data = 
gon.two_months_ago_label = (Date.today - 2.month).strftime("%B")
gon.two_months_ago_data = 
gon.three_months_ago_label = (Date.today - 3.month).strftime("%B")
gon.three_months_ago_data = 
gon.four_months_ago_label = (Date.today - 4.month).strftime("%B")
gon.four_months_ago_data = 
gon.five_months_ago_label = (Date.today - 5.month).strftime("%B")
gon.five_months_ago_data =
```

But also need the corresponding data.

I tried something like this

```
gon.now_month_data = SentMessage.where(created_at.month: (Date.today).strftime("%B") ).count
```

But it failed.Besides it can search for others years and not exactly a month ago.
  Any idea of how i can construct Queries to get the information.

We need to have data like say November : 2034 messages and October: 5330

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gon.three_months_ago_data = SentMessage.where('created_at > ? and created_at < ?', Date.today.beginning_of_month - 3.months, Date.today.beginning_of_month - 2.months).count
```

Comment: This however does not cover the specific months.. does it? say i want November..`SentMessage.where('created_at > ? and created_at < ?', 2.months.ago, 0.months.ago).count` just calculates months ago not the 30 window period

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [by star](https://github.com/radar/by_star) plugin which lets you do things like:

```
SentMessage.by_month("January") # of current year

SentMessage.by_month("January",:year => 2007)

SentMessage.by_month(1, :year => 2007)

SentMessage.between(time1, time2)
```